# Query strings with HTTP URL

Tags: html, http, url, browser, web

I am trying to do a HTTP GET of an URL with multiple query strings using a browser. Following is my observation

```
http://192.168.0.1:80/mycontent/?key1=value1 //Works.
http://192.168.0.1:80/mycontent/?key1=value1&key2=value2 //Doesen't work.
```

The question here :

- I am finding a hard time to figure out what's the right format to
  append the query string
- Should we use `&amp` when we put in the browser?
- Is there a way that I can find the validity (availability in the server) of the query string I enter in the URL.

Comment: Define "doesn't work"? If you paste the second URL in the browser, the values of `key1` and `key2` should end up at the server.

Comment: Actually the URL refers to a video stream. With the first one, I am able to download the stream, while second doesent allow me to.

Comment: We cannot say anything about that. The browser will pass `key1` and `key2` in the second case. "Doesn't allow me to" also isn't an error, the issue is in the `mycontent` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `&amp;` when writing the link into HTML, for example:

```
<a href="http://192.168.0.1:80/mycontent/?key1=value1&amp;key2=value2">Example</a>
```

But not when entering the URL into the address bar, or using it directly in JavaScript (for example).

Your format is correct, so you should be able to pick up both `key1` and `key2` in the request collection. Depending on the language you are using on the server, the technique for this differs.

Comment: Thanks sir. Now my suspicion  turns into the server side implementation